# Control-clicking not showing context menu in Chrome under OS X

Tags: javascript, html, macos, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

I'm trying to debug some code on a web page in Chrome Developer Tools on Mac OS X.  Because this is a Mac and I have trackpad, there is no "right click" button, instead I have to hold down the "control" key when I click.  I am trying to do this on a page to bring up the context menu so that I can quickly jump to the element in the elements tab of developer tools, because otherwise it is a laborious and error prone process of trying to navigate through every element to find where a particular element is.

The problem is, on the page I am debugging, control click doesn't bring up a context menu! Instead, it just toggles highlighting the text I am clicking on. I thought that maybe a click handler I installed on some element on the page was interfering, but even when I disable javascript on the page I get the same behavior. I think it must be something about my page that is causing this interference, because on other pages I see the correct behavior, but what?

Comment: https://gigaom.com/2008/08/21/mac-101-enable-right-click-on-macs/

Comment: @hopkins-matt That's already enabled, and the secondary click gesture (appears to be tap with two fingers) has the same effect as control clicking.  It's only on the page I'm trying to debug that it doesn't work.